# Send custom string to AWS SNS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have completed the Lambda (Nodejs)project. Now I want to include the funny part.
I have a service that sends data to AWS Topic. Then I have subscribers to the topic, who receive the email.
I want to include some ascii art at the bottom of the mail.

The issue I have, the ascii is malformed when it arrives in the email. I have manage to manually correct small art, but I would want to include bigger ones as well.
Here is the [place](https://www.asciiart.eu/) I take the art

```
const bug = "Some art taken from the site"

const params = {
  TargetArn: process.env.SNS_TOPIC_ARN,
  Message: `Bla bla bla some text. \n\n \n\n ${bug} \n\n FIX the bug. `,
  Subject: `Some subject`
};
```

How should I include the ascii so it arrives not deformed.

This is how it looks when I paste it from the website directly in the code:

```
const bug = "/\\/\\\n" +
    "   \\_\\  _..._\n" +
    "   (\" )(_..._)\n" +
    "     ^^  // \\\\";
```

I have to manually correct it, mainly spaces.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASCII art normally relies on the use of a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font).

Your users are probably receiving the message on modern phones that uses a [proportional font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Proportional_font), thus impacting the display.

If you wish to control the formatting of a message, you will need to send it as a normal email message with HTML formatting using **Amazon Simple Email Service (Amazon SES)** rather than sending it directly through an Amazon SNS message.